# RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu

Tags: python, pytorch, cosine-similarity, flair

```
import asyncio
import torch
import os
import pandas as pd
from flair.data import Sentence
from flair.embeddings import FlairEmbeddings, DocumentPoolEmbeddings, WordEmbeddings



device = torch.device("cpu")
print(device)
# first, declare how you want to embed
embeddings = DocumentPoolEmbeddings(
    [WordEmbeddings('glove'), FlairEmbeddings('news-forward'), FlairEmbeddings('news-backward')])


path = os.getcwd()

df=pd.read_pickle(path+'/embedding_all_courses_2.pkl')



query_emd=[]
cos = torch.nn.CosineSimilarity(dim=0, eps=1e-6)



query= Sentence("some text")
embeddings.embed([query])
query_emd.append(query.embedding)



async def count(index,row):
    for i in query_emd:
        print(words,row['course_name'],cos(i, row['embedding']))
        
    print(index)
    

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*(count(index,row) for index,row in df.iterrows()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time
    s = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main())
    
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
    print(f"{__file__} executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds.")
```

Trying to run pytorch cosine similarity in asyncio package to get the parallel result. Using a flair model for embedding text. Need to compare a text with a huge dataframe and get the most similar text as a result and response should be pretty fast. Can you please suggest an alternative way also? I also need to run this code on the CPU memory only not on the GPU Cuda system

Error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyn_emd.py", line 74, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 579, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/asyn_emd.py", line 68, in main
    await asyncio.gather(*(count(index,row) for index,row in df.iterrows()))
  File "/asyn_emd.py", line 61, in count
    print(words,row['course_name'],cos(i, row['embedding']))
  File "/home/karthickaravindan/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 722, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/karthickaravindan/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/distance.py", line 75, in forward
    return F.cosine_similarity(x1, x2, self.dim, self.eps)
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!
```

Comment: make sure that at ```cos(i, row["embedding"])```i and row["embedding"] are both on the CPU. I dont know what these variables are but I think one of them is on gpu. So add ```.to(device="cpu")``` to i and row["embedding"]

Comment: @TheodorPeifer Thank you. It worked.  print(words,row['course_name'],cos(i.to(device="cpu"),row['embedding'].to(device="cpu")))